# $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of the equation $x^3 − 9x + 9 = 0$. Find the value of $ \alpha^{-5}+\beta^{-5}+\gamma^{-5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots, symmetric-polynomials

I've simplified the expression to get
$$\frac{(\alpha\beta)^5+(\beta\gamma)^5+(\gamma\alpha)^5}{(\alpha\beta\gamma)^5}.$$

Now all I need to find is $\sum (\alpha\beta)^5$ given that $\sum \alpha\beta=-9$ (by Vieta's relations).

If it helps, I found that:
$$\sum (\alpha\beta)^2=81,$$ and
$$\sum (\alpha\beta)^3=-486.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quite quick solution using linear recurrences.

Replacing $x=\frac 1y$  in $x^3 − 9x + 9 = 0$ we conclude 
$$\frac 1{\alpha},\frac 1{\beta},\frac 1{\gamma} \text{ are the roots of }y^3-y^2+\frac 19=0$$

So, $$\frac 1{\alpha^{-5}}+\frac 1{\beta^{-5}}+\frac 1{\gamma^{-5}} = a_5$$

in the recursion

$$a_{n+3} = a_{n+2}-\frac 19 a_n \text{ with } a_0 = \frac 1{\alpha^{0}}+\frac 1{\beta^{0}}+\frac 1{\gamma^{0}}=1$$

Vieta gives the other starting values

$$a_1 = 1, a_2 = a_1^2 - 2\cdot 0 = 1$$

Now, 
$$a_3 =1-\frac 13 = \frac 23,\; a_4 = \frac 23 - \frac 19= \frac 59$$

and finally

$$a_5 = \frac 59 - \frac 19 = \boxed{\frac 49}$$

Comment: This is a very nice idea! I would suggest you to incorporate this description in your answer. Besides there seems to be a typo in the second formula.

Comment: Yes. You are right about that typo in my comment. It should be $b_0a_n$. Unfortunately comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes. I will delete it and repost it for those who also might want to know how my answer works. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: repost: 
@user :The idea behind my answer is rather that the general solution of a linear recurrence of degree $3$: $a_{n+3}+b_2a_{n+2}+b_1a_{n+1}+b_0a_n=0$ is of the form $a_n =c_1t_1^n + c_2t_2^n+c_3t_3^n$, if $t_1,t_2,t_3$ are $3$ different roots of the equation $t^3+b_2t^2+b_1t+b_0=0$. In the given case I only needed the polynomial with $t_1 =\frac 1{\alpha}, t_2=\frac 1{\beta},t_3=\frac 1{\gamma}$ as roots and the searched for number corresponds to $c_1=c_2=c_3=1$ and $n=5$. The symmetric polynomials only come into play  when calculating the starting values $a_0,a_1,a_2$.

Answer (score 3):

You can express $\sum(\alpha\beta)^5$ in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials by the standard method, by repeatedly subtracting the first monomial in the lexicographical order. Here's the first step:
$$\sum(\alpha\beta)^5-\left(\sum(\alpha\beta)\right)^5=5\sum\alpha^5\beta^4\gamma+10\sum\alpha^5\beta^3\gamma^2+20\sum\alpha^4\beta^4\gamma^2+30\sum\alpha^4\beta^3\gamma^3.$$
The next step would be to subtract $5(\sum\alpha)^{5-4}(\sum\alpha\beta)^{4-1}(\sum\alpha\beta\gamma)^{1-0}$. This is a bit tedious, but you should eventually find a polynomial in the symmetric sums consisting of $7$ monomials.

Alternatively, you can look up [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and plug in your values.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everyone who solved it, but I've solved it myself now.

Let $a=\alpha\beta, b=\beta\gamma, c=\gamma\alpha$.
a,b,c are the roots of $x^3+9x^2-81=0$

We know that
$$a(a^3+9a^2-81)=0$$
$$a^4+9a^3-81a=0$$      (1)
$$b^4+9b^3-81b=0$$      (2)
$$c^4+9c^3-81c=0$$      (3)

Adding (1), (2) and (3)
$$\sum a^4 + 9\sum a^3 -81\sum a=0$$
$$\sum a^4 = -9\sum a^3 +81\sum a=3645$$

Similarly we get,
$$\sum a^5= -9\sum a^4 +81\sum a^2=-26244$$

Now,
$$\alpha^{-5}+\beta^{-5}+\gamma^{-5} = \frac{\sum a^5}{-9^5}$$
$$=\frac{-26244}{-9^5}=\frac{4}{9}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\alpha^{-1}, b=\beta^{-1},c=\gamma^{-1}.$ Then, we have $a+b+c=\alpha^{-1}+\beta^{-1}+\gamma^{-1}=(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)/(\alpha\beta\gamma)=1,$ $abc=(\alpha\beta\gamma)^{-1}=-1/9,$ and $ab+bc+ca=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)/(\alpha\beta\gamma)=0.$ Then, we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\alpha^{-5}+\beta^{-5}+\gamma^{-5}&=a^5+b^5+c^5\\
&=(a+b+c)^5-5(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)^3\\
&\ \ \ \ \ +5abc(a+b+c)^2+5(ab+bc+ca)^2(a+b+c)\\
&\ \ \ \ \ -5abc(ab+bc+ca),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and all that is left to do is substitute.

P.S. The equation above can be obtained by repeated use of [Newton's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which can be used to express $a^i+b^i+c^i$ using the basic symmetric polynomials $a+b+c,ab+bc+ca,abc.$

Comment: How did you find the coefficients $(1,-5,5,5,-5)$?

Comment: By repeated use of Newton's identities.

Comment: I would suggest to mention this in the answer.